# Inserir string de HTML na página, com fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom uso os seguinte código em jquery para adicionar um div no site:

```
$("body").append('<div class="shadow-full"></div>');
```

Porém ela aparece de uma vez, queria colocar um efeito para ela aparecer com mais suavidade, tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de separar isso em passos.

- converte essa string de HTML num elemento
- esconde-o
- insere-o no DOM
- faz fade in

Para fazer isso *"à lá jQuery"*  poderia ser assim:

```js
$('<div class="shadow-full">Teste!</div>')
  .hide()
  .appendTo("body")
  .fadeIn(1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: vlw, muito obrigado